# how solve Cyclotomic Polynomial , n=8

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

[image]

how i can access to red box ${ \frac{x^8-1}{x^4-1}  }$ ?? and how complete my solution to end result ?

Comment: What is $\mu(k)$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but $x^8-1=(x^4)^2-(1)^2=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$

Comment: @Aqua:  cf. [Mobius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(x-1)^{\mu (8)}(x^2-1)^{\mu (4)}(x^4-1)^{\mu (2)}(x^8-1)^{\mu (1)}$$
$$=(x-1)^{0}(x^2-1)^{0}(x^4-1)^{-1}(x^8-1)^{1}$$
$$ {x^8-1\over x^4-1} = {(x^4-1)(x^4+1)\over x^4-1} = x^4+1$$

Comment: For the final stage, where you get a fraction with polynomials upstairs and downstairs, one may need to perform polynomial division, as is usually taught in high schools. Here, the final stage is easy, as you demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

Difference of two squares:

$x^8-1=(x^4)^2-(1)^2=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$,

so $\bbox[white,5px,border:2px solid red] {\dfrac{x^8-1}{x^4-1}}=x^4+1=\Phi_8(x).$